# Editing Excel timeline X axis

Tags: excel, charts, timeline

I have a timeline chart made using a scatter graph. I want to edit the X axis so it is thick and has labels for different Phases.  I created an image of the chart style I am looking to create.

Can anyone let me know what to search or help on how I can format my chart.

Current Timeline:
[image: Current Timeline]

Wanted Timeline look:
[image: Want I want to see]

Thank you

Comment: Why would this get down voted? Interesting.